# Typescript: error Enum can't convert undefined to object (Enum undefined)

Tags: typescript, enums

I have this enum:

```
export enum ValoriScadenzario {
    Niente = "NESSUN FILTRO",
    Sanzione = "SANZIONE",
    Prescrizione = "PRESCRIZIONE",
    Azione ="AZIONE",
    Prelievo = "PRELIEVO UNICA ISTANZA"
}
```

declared in a .ts file. I want to use this enum in another class, but Typescript is telling me runtime that "ValoriScadenzario" is undefined. I'm doing this:

```
import { ValoriScadenzario } from '../../enums/scadenzario-enum';
...
Object.keys(ValoriScadenzario)
```

I've checked other answers but problems were missing export, const declaration, or moved enum file... I'm not finding an answer to this, what am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "TypeScript is telling me that it is undefined"?  What exact error are you getting and where exactly are you seeing it?  Ideally you would provide a [mcve] so that others can help you, such as a link to a standalone web IDE like [this](https://repl.it/@jcalz/BogusMulticoloredMemorypool) (where I cannot reproduce your issue).  Note that if you *can't* reproduce the issue yourself in a different environment from your current one, then nobody else will be able to either.  And in such cases, you can start debugging by carefully comparing the two environments.  Good luck!

Comment: I just tested your code and its working as expected.

Comment: You may be mistaken about the location of `scadenzario-enum.js` at runtime.  Check the compiled JavaScript folder/file structure.  It might be that you need to change your `tsconfig.json` so that it outputs JavaScript in the right way.  I strongly recommend you try to reproduce the issue in some sort of standalone IDE like [repl.it](https://repl.it).

Comment: I've solved it, it was a mistake in the name of the file. It wanted .component.ts but I named it just .ts.